# I keep getting "must be a vector" error in r when using "mi" package

Tags: r, vector, error-handling, mi

I'm trying to impute missing data with the "mi" package in r and I keep getting an error on all my variables

My code:
`mdf <- missing_data.frame(data.frame)`

Error I get:

> Error in .guess_type(y, favor_ordered, favor_positive, threshold, variable_name) : 
>     age : must be a vector

When I check type:

```
typeof(data.frame$age)
```

I get:

> [1] "double"

Anyone know the best way to fix this?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 
If you could share some sample code, it will help us understand the issue better.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a tibble and needed to be a data.frame for this function. This worked:

```
datasetdf <- as.data.frame(dataset)
mdf <- missing_data.frame(datasetdf)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late but I was having the same issue and tried changing it from tibble it still didn't work.

This is what worked:
y = as.vector(y)

Thought it might be helpful to someone.